# Getting Run ID of Manually Invoked GitHub Workflow Using REST API

Tags: github-api

I am writing an automation routine that will include manually running a GitHub Workflow. I need to monitor the status of the workflow and download the logs once it’s finished.

Everything is fairly straightforward. The only missing link in the chain is how to determine the run ID for the workflow that I just invoked. There is no information that comes back from the REST API call (/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/dispatches endpoint) in either the body or the headers that gives me that information.

How can I determine what the run ID is for the workflow when it is invoked?